# How to import a data file by alphabetical filename, preferably using tidyverse

Tags: r

I'm trying to create some production code, and I'm a newbie at this. I want my R script to import the a csv file that has the most recent date in the file name (e.g., import "data20190515.csv" instead of "data20190510.csv"). Can anyone point me in the right direction, preferably in the tidyverse? Love how helpful SO is!

Googled examples on StackOverflow, Github and R-Bloggers.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any additional packages. If your file names are standardized you can list your files in the directory and sort it in descending order and pull the first element.

```
files <- list.files(path)
most_recent_file_path <- sort(files, decreasing = TRUE)[1]
most_recent_file <- read.csv(most_recent_file_path)
```

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I didn't ask specifically enough. There are mixed files in the directory, like "newdata20190519.csv", "newdata20190518.csv", "olddata20190519.csv", "olddate20190518.csv". I need the script to import the "newdata" or "olddata" prefix whenever appropriate. How would I pick up a specific file that starts with a filename string?

Comment: you would need to write a regular expression to parse the filename, could you provide all formats of filenames above as well as the conditions needed?